# How do I enable Add-ins using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to enable one of Excel's default add-ins with VBA, and it looks like I'm typing a boolean instead of a method. All of the information I find tells me that this should enable the the Solver Add-in.

```
AddIns("Solver Add-in").Installed = True
```

But it doesn't. Instead, it returns "Compile Error: Invalid outside procedure."

How do I enable the Solver Add-in when a worksheet opens?

Edit:

I'm running this code because I have to put methods inside subroutines. The problem is that it returns "Compile Error: Can't find project or library."

```
Option Base 1
Sub TurnOnSolver()
AddIns("Solver Add-in").Installed = True
End Sub

TurnOnSolver

Function cubic_spline(input_column As Range, _
                  output_column As Range, _
                  x As Range)

' The function does stuff that requires Solver Add-in.

End Function
```

Comment: Where is that code located?  Executable statements need to be in a Sub or Function.

Comment: Invalid outside procedure is the clue. Show your code & where do you put it?

Comment: I'm trying to run it before Excel starts implementing a custom function. I can make a subroutine that contains the line, but then I'll need to run that subroutine before Excel tries to read my custom function.

Comment: @Absinthe Is that better?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a method outside of a sub or function, it has to be within a code block.

I'd suggest putting the call in the [workbook open event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/workbook-open-event-excel); double click the workbook object in the project explorer and paste this code in:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
     AddIns("Solver Add-in").Installed = True
End Sub
```

Alternatively, if you have a main sub put it in there. As a last resort you could put it in your cubic_spline function but presumably that will be called quite often so I'd advise against it.

Comment: Works fine for me, even in the immediate window. What did you try?